# Rails - Current URL without locale part passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, locale, rails-i18n

In my Rails app I scope locale into my urls:

```
http://localhost:3000/de/blah/blubb
http://localhost:3000/en/blah/blubb
http://localhost:3000/es/blah/blubb
                     ^^^
```

**How can I "get" the current_url without the locale parameter?**

```
http://localhost:3000/blah/blubb
                    ^^^
```

At the moment I have this:

```
<%=  "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath}" %>
# http://localhost:3000/de/blah/blubb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a list of available locales you want to exclude:

```
LOCALES = %w(en de es).map { |l| l.prepend '/' }
```

Then you can replace them like this:

```
<%= "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath.sub(Regexp.union(LOCALES), '')}" %>
# /blah/blubb
```

Comment: ok this works, but visitors have also the possibility to visit ```http:localhost:3000/blah/blubb``` and the result with your solution strips out my ```http:localhost:3000/blubb``` . So the ```blah``` is missing. Can you please update your answer?

Comment: fullpath.s.sub? Where does the s come from? and is L the LOCALES?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this pattern

```
http://localhost:3000/X/blah/blubb
```

where X can be a locale but can also sometimes be something else, then you will need to specify the list of locales and gsub them out:

```
"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}#{request.fullpath.gsub(/^\/#{array_of_locale_strings.map{|s| "(#{s})"}.join("|")}\//,"/")}"
```